# Laravel format to 1 decimal place

Tags: php, laravel, decimal, rounding

```html
@if($user->dettagli->facebook_follower >= 1000 && $user->dettagli->facebook_follower <= 999999)

    <?php
         echo(round($user->dettagli->facebook_follower, 5,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "K");
     ?>
                     
     {{$user->dettagli->facebook_follower / 1000}} K
                        
@endif
```

Hi could someone please help me. I am using Laravel and trying to display a users Facebook follower count, but I got a little stuck with something. I am taking their int at for example 1589 followers and trying to return in the blade "1.5k". On screen I return either 1589k with this php call or 1.589k. How do I get that number to one decimal place and become only 1.5k??
thank you!

Comment: Divide it by 1000, round and format to one decimal place, add `k` suffix

Comment: I don't want to come across as a bit of a dick, but over the course of the last few weeks; you've been asking the same things. I strongly suggest that before you start work on a project in Laravel, you [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) first. Once you understand it, then start a project and come to us when you have some question. At the moment, you seem to be asking us a question at every step of the way. **How is this question, different to [the one you asked the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587812/laravel-format-numbers-from-user-input-or-in-db)**

Answer (score 2):

As per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

> Returns the rounded value of val to specified precision (number of digits after the decimal point). precision can also be negative or zero (default).

You are specifying a precision of `5`. You should change this to `1`.

Change your function call to:

```
echo(round($user->dettagli->facebook_follower, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "K");
```

EDIT: I mis-read the question. This is a function that should handle numbers into the millions.

You would need to use [laravel-twigbridge](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-twigbridge) to make the function available in your templates though.

```
function pretty_number(int $n): string {
    $prettyN = $n;
    $suffix = '';
    $len = strlen((string) $n);
    $suffixes = ['K', 'M'];
    foreach ($suffixes as $s) {
        if ($n < 1000) {
            break;
        }
        $suffix = $s;
        $n = $n / 1000;
        $prettyN = number_format($n, 1);
    }
    return $prettyN . $suffix;
}

echo pretty_number(100); // 100
echo pretty_number(999); // 99
echo pretty_number(1589); // 1.6K
echo pretty_number(1600); // 1.6K
echo pretty_number(1589300); // 1.6M
```

Comment: Wouldn't this display something like `1589K` if you had 1589 followers?

Comment: Sorry I began with that and as Nigel says it returned 1589

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.numberformatter.php). This can be defined in a global place so you only need to use the third line in your blade view.

```php
$a = new \NumberFormatter("en-US", \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$a->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 1); 
echo $a->format($user->dettagli->facebook_follower);
```